# Will existing Ubuntu installation still work on this new hardware?

Tags: hardware

I currently have the following CPU:

> model name : AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 240e Processor
>   stepping    : 2
>   microcode   : 0x10000b7
>   cpu MHz  : 2800.000
>   cache size  : 1024 KB

on the following mainboard:

> Product: 785GT-E63(MS-7551)
>   Vendor: MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD

I plan to get a new CPU Intel i7 and a new corresponding mainboard but keep the SSD, graphic card and wireless card?

Does anyone know if my existing Ubuntu installation will still work on this new hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Linux works with general drivers.

I have taken out my hard disc from broken systems almost 10 times now and inserted the old hard disc into a brand new system and **it just works** <sup>(tm)</sup>.

All you have to take into account that if your switch videocard brand (from NVidia to AMD or from AMD to Nvidia) is to remove the restricted driver if you have that installed (ie. in general you need to remove all 3rd party drivers you installed for hardware that does not come with the new system).

Try it. I believe you will be amazed at how easy it is to do this. You will not even have to re-install the OS; just pop the hard into the new system.

---

I would advice to not buy a motherboard that uses UEFI (if possible). It might work as I posted above here by turning UEFI off but there is no guarantee. Due to the nature of this piece of ... it might fail since the hardware changed and a re-install might be obligatory.

Comment: Unless of course you used BIOS (MBR) and now you use UEFI (GPT) in which case, **be prepared** (patent pending).

Comment: Ah that crap again @UriHerrera I bet it is too much to ask for it to work OOTB...

Comment: It works, yes, but I really don't know why the problem is if you keep two OS in one drive with a motherboard using UEFI, if you use two drives for each system there's no problem at all and everything works fine.