# Will hardware changes affect system?

Tags: 12.10, server, hardware

I have ubuntu production server 12.10 x64 installed on system with hi end hardware. I want to change mainboard, cpu, and ram to older ones. Basically from current system only hdd will remain unchanged. Is that safe to do? Can I do it without reinstalling system?

Comment: See answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/237614/will-existing-ubuntu-installation-still-work-on-this-new-hardware

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to change your motherboard, cpu and ram, without needing to reinstall Ubuntu. I do however recommend a backup.

Comment: I agree, changing RAM, Motherboard, and CPU won't be as much of an issue, however back up all your files anyways before changing hardware.

Comment: even if I change the cpu from i5 to core duo? and mainboard that Ill change to is intel 945 chipset

Comment: @hunter The motherboard also comes with on board graphics too, so the main issue here is that the system will support the CPU and probably the RAM, but the graphics might need additional drivers installed, however it still should boot.  Even then, back up your files.  Whenever you're doing maintenance to your system (hardware, upgrading, or otherwise) you should back up files you don't ever want to lose.  Just in case.

Comment: man it's ubuntu server, without gui.

Comment: it doesnt use graphics card

Comment: @hunter You didn't say that in your initial post, however it's still the same point, back up your data anyways.  Information Technology 101: keep backups.

Comment: lol friend, dont you see ubuntu production server words in my question?

Comment: If I gave you the correct answer please mark it as approved and with the rest of the comments I think they are all unnecessary. please stop it.